# How to correctly use "yAxisID" for a Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, yaxis, quickchart

I am new to using Chart.js objects and have run into a bug or syntax error using "yAxisID" as a property of my datasets. I am sending to QuickChart using the PowerShell command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://quickchart.io/chart/create" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json"
```

Note that the png outfile approach seems to work fine..

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://quickchart.io/chart" -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -OutFile <outfile.png>"
```

Here is the `$json`

```
{
  data: {
    labels: [
      '2022Dec2',
      '2022Dec7',
      '2022Dec12',
      '2022Dec22',
      '2022Dec27',
      '2022Dec30',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [0.0, -3.38, -1.96, -6.44, -6.27, -6.02],
        label: 'SPY',
        borderDash: [1, 0],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#4E79A7',
        yAxisID: 'y',
      },
      {
        data: [0.0, -4.11, -2.38, -8.82, -9.9, -8.98],
        label: 'QQQ',
        borderDash: [1, 0],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#F28E2B',
        yAxisID: 'y1',
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      text: 'Stock Symbol % Change',
      display: true,
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          position: 'left',
          id: 'y',
          display: true,
        },
        {
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          },
          id: 'y1',
          display: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
    },
  },
  type: 'line',
}
```

I tried deleting the "yAxisID" lines of the `$json` and that seems to work fine (although on just a single y-axis). I am expecting the "yAxisID" lines to plot the first dataset on the left y-axis and the second dataset on the right y-axis.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are encountering a syntax error, or a QuickChart error, or just a chart that doesn't quite look right?  The chart config looks generally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scales: {
      Y: 
        {
          position: 'left',
          id: 'y',
          display: true,
        },

        Y1{
          display: 'auto',
           id: 'y1',
          position: 'right',         
          grid: {
            drawOnChartArea: false,
          }
                   
        }   
    },
```